# Have TextMate indicate which files are out of date in regard to a GIT project

Tags: git, textmate

I just created a GIT project and I have it open in TextMate, and I am wondering if I can get the file explorer to mark files when they are different from the latest commit. I am coming from using IntelliJ so I am used to the file names changing color when I make a change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you install the [Project+](http://ciaranwal.sh/2008/08/05/textmate-plug-in-projectplus) plugin you'll find that it has the option to add icon status flags next to the filenames. Be aware that on Lion and later it causes TextMate to crash quite often though, so it might not be a usable solution.

Comment: Thanks @eugen, it looks like it hasn't been updated in over 4 years so I don't think I will go with it. Maybe I will write my own plugin...

Answer (score 0):

TextMate 2 has git badges in its file browser. It's still in beta but open source and pretty usable if you ask me.

https://github.com/textmate/textmate